# Third party email service and SPF

Tags: email, spf

I am using third party email service (mailing list, like Mailchimp or similar) and I have included ip-address of that server on SPF record in my domain name.

Same third party email service is used 10 other users and those users does not see each other.

What will happend if somebody else uses that same third party server and send spam with my address from it? Is that email rejected on target server or not? If not, can i somehow prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

SPF cannot protect against this, but DKIM can - this is why you need to use both.

Comment: But if messages are signed with correct DKIM and sent from the allowed server how the target server could tell should it reject message or not?

Comment: The third party could sign messages with the list sender's key, but they cannot sign messages with *your* DKIM key, and you can set your DMARC policy to reject.

Comment: But how that same server could sign messages if i send them from that same server?

Comment: You'd need to have the sender use a custom key and selector for your account that other accounts would not have access to. Ultimately there is trust of your sender involved.